# How to reference shared files and folders in Google Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to port code from a  Jupyter Notebook into a Colab Notebook so that I can share a working MobileNet image classifer. I am struggling to reference  shared folders and files,

The original Jupyter Notebook (based on this [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/OO4HD-1wRN8?t=3m38s)) contains two types of reference

1)  A relative path reference. e.g.
 img_path = **'MobileNet-inference-images/'**

2) A file in the above directory. e.g.
preprocessed_image = prepare_image(**'American_Cam.jpg'**)

Most of my attempts have focused on trying to reference a Google drive folder (also called "MobileNet-inference-image") & the "American_Cam.jpg" file inside. The shared folder is located [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HVkbHS_NTLZSYzdoYBQjCmJ6GHQ4PN_I) .

I have failed to find an working example that references both files and folders in google drive. For example - [this approach](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q#scrollTo=Q0u3VR-gmbF4) errors out for me.

For reference my  Colab Notebook with associated links and code [is here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x5GS5KbX47cxE3DpYnn_kHNlJ-5QzINP).

Any suggestions, or advice on alternative approaches welcome.

Comment: This might help: https://qiita.com/Rowing0914/items/51a770925653c7c528f9

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Google Drive and go to "Shared with me". Select the shared folder and drag&drop it onto your drive "My Drive". This will create a shortcut to the shared folder. In Google Colab you can see the shared folder under "content"->"gdrive"->"my Drive"-> "your shared folder"

Answer (score 1):

Do these steps and try to show (`!ls`) the file again.

- Go to your [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/)
- Find **shared folder**
- Right click it
- Click `Add to My Drive`

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a "Shared Drive" (different from "Shared with me"), you need the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/ShardDrives/")
```

The "Shared Drive" should now appear in the left file menu. You can the right click on the desired file or folder to obtain the path (which is not immediately obvious).

Comment: SharedDrives does appear on my left menu, but it doesn't actually contain the shared drives. It has my normal drive folders